Collector and Emitter of BJT are always shorted

I am testing a circuit and i have an npn BJT in that.
I am supplying a 5V pulsed source to the base of the BJT at node C. And a constant -5V input at node A. Note the frequency must be 10KHz with 10% duty cycle.
My output is at node B.
My requirement is such that once i give both the inputs, I must get a pulse switching from -5V to -2.5V with the same frequency as pulsed input(10KHz, 10%duty cycle) at node B.
The functionality of the circuit expected is:-
When the base receives a high, it will turn on and the collector and emitter will get shorted to ground. And a potential divider will be formed by 1k potentiometer in parallel with 1k and the 500 ohm resistor. Thus i will get -2.5V output
When the base receives a low, BJT must turn off and hence the collector must be in floating and at the output i must get -5V.
Thus it must switch between -5V and -2.5V as explained above. But at the output i am getting a pulse witching between -2.5V and -2.6V
Observation in the BJT
When i am turning on the source to the BJT, VBE=0.7V and the BJT is turned ON and at that instant VCE=0V.
When i am turning off the pulsed input at the base of the BJT, VBE=0V but VCE=0V.
There is no problem with the BJT. The pins are not shorted yet i am getting VCE=0V.
I have changed different part numbers, but the behaviour is the same.
Note that the potentiometer is used to achieve the pulsed output at node C to switch between -5V and -2.5V~-3.5V
Please suggest if there are any changes required in the circuit to acheive the desired result

There are no simple changes to your circuit which will make it work - you cannot use an NPN BJT in that way. Applying or removing BE biasing does not turn the CE oath into a simple on/off switch. Consider that BC is also a 'diode' junction, and you're forward-biasing it constantly no matter whether you apply 5V or 0V to your 'pulsed input'. You'll find that even disconnecting the emitter completely will have little to no impact on the behavior of this circuit. You need a completely different circuit to achieve your goal here.

Change the transistor to a PNP type in a common-base configuration.  Collector to the two 1K parts, base to GND, input drives the emitter through a resistor.

@brhans Thank you for the response. Can you please provide a picture of the circuit which you think would work

Change the transistor to a PNP type in a common-base configuration. Collector to the two 1K parts, base to GND, input drives the emitter through a resistor.
Adjust the values of R2 and R3 for the desired output voltage range.
Note that this circuit is non-inverting.  When the input moves in a positive-going direction, the output moves in a positive-going direction.
If the possibility of the output going above 0.0 V is a problem, add a small signal diode (1N914, 1N4148, etc.) between the Q1 collector and R2.
With R3 = 1 K, there is no value of R2 that will allow the output signal to go down to -3.5 V.  With R2 oper circuit, the output will reach only -3.16 V.

UPDATE:
Here is an alternate version of the circuit.  Keeping R4 at the original value, R2 and R3 have been adjusted for the desired output voltage range.  They are easier to calculate as series, rather than parallel, resistors, but the output impedance is the same either way.  Because R3 is in series with R2 rather than in parallel, it can remain a 1 K part while the circuit exceeds the output voltage requirement.
Of course, all four resistor values can be scaled for a different output voltage range and/or a different output impedance.

NOTE:
As GodJihyo points out: for Q1 to saturate, R1 cannot be 1.0K.  In fact, it must be less than 781 ohms in both circuits.  The schematics have been corrected.
UPDATE2:
For the second schematic only and keeping R4 a constant 499 ohms, R2 sets the limit for the higher output voltage (-2.25 V with the values shown) and (R2 + R3) sets the lower output voltage.
For example, if you keep R2 at 499 ohms, then increasing R3 to a 10K pot lowers the maximum low output voltage to -4.75 V.  This is calculated with Ohm's Law.

I tried simulating this in LTspice and I didn't get the same results, R1 affects the output voltage quite a bit as it is basically part of the divider. I have to bring it down to around 850Ω and set R3 to zero to get -2.5V out. Increasing R1 to 2.2k or 4.7k wouldn't let the output get anywhere near -2.5V.

You are correct.  I got a little carried away.  The worst-case collector current is 5.5 mA, and the R1 voltage drop has to be less than 4.3 V at that current, for a max. value of 781 ohms.  I'll update the answer.

Common-base switching sometimes feels like lost art. Nice.

Logic level translation and RF amplifiers - strange bedfellows.

@AnalogKid   Thank you. I have tested by placing resistors in both series and parallel. It is working in both the cases. I also have a query that if i want to switch my output between -5V and -2.5V~-5V, then which resistor value should i change?

You can do this with two transistors, an NPN followed by a PNP, assuming you have +5 V available (since you're feeding it 5 V pulses this seems reasonable).
Here's an example circuit:

It's shown with a 10kHz 10% duty cycle pulse. R5 and C1 along with the transistors used help speed it up, you could play around with the values depending on how fast you need the transitions.
